# Array of objects from multiple loops

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, object

I would like to end up with an array of custom objects. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to go about this when I have multiple arrays to iterate through in order to create the custom objects. I have something like this:

```
class CustomObject {
    var name = ""
    var place = ""
    var price = ""
}

var nameArray = [“name1”,"name2","name3"]
var placeArray = [“place1”,"place2","place3"]
var priceArray [“price1”,"price2","price3"]
var customArray [CustomObject]()
createObject(name : nameArray, place : placeArray, price : priceArray)

func createObject(name : [String], place : [String], price : [String]) {
    let instance = CustomObject()
    for names in name {
        instance.name = names
    }
    for places in place {
        instance.place = places
    }
    for prices in price {
        instance.price = prices
        customArray.append(instance)
    }
}
```

I would like to end up with an array of those custom "instances". Right now my code is giving each attribute the last index of each array.

Comment: that code has multiple compiler errors, please post code that is closer to compiling + an example of where your code actually fails + the desired outcome in that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try , also i suppose all the arrays have the same count

```
 var customArray = [CustomObject]()

  for  i in 0..<nameArray.count {

       let instance = CustomObject()

       instance.name = nameArray[i]

       instance.place = placeArray[i]

       instance.price = priceArray[i]

       customArray.append(instance)
 }
```